# How can I insert an imageView behind a UITableView in a fixed position (no scrolling)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to insert an image behind my table view using:

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newpink120"]];
    imageView.frame=CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width-60, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-60-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, 60, 60);
    [self.tableView addSubview:imageView];
    [self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

This seems to work but the image scrolls with the table. Is there anyway to keep it fixed in the bottom right corner?

Comment: try this     [tableview setBackgroundView:view]

Comment: I tried this, can't see the image. Then I set the background colour to clear but the table behaves strange and the background is black

Comment: Another approach is not making UIImageView subview of tableView and make it to subview of UIView. And then make UITableView and UITableViewCell background color as clear

Comment: in your XIB add one image view with your background image and set background view of table nil and color clear color. it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating a static tableview background, you have to do 2 things

1) set `self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

2) and then initialise the table background view with an UIImageView and set the image you want to show there.

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]] ];
```

Comment: the problem is setting the colour to clear. For some reason it makes the background black and then the cell scroll behaviour acts strangely.

Comment: is it a custom tableView or just default? how you are doing it?

Comment: default. I tried changing the colour in code and in the interface builder.

Comment: may be you messed with something, try to delete and drop new tableView and try it, I guess it should work!

Comment: does the imageView have to be the same size as the window or something to cover the whole background?

Comment: You can have small image, it will repeat it self. if you have gradient image then need long strip image.

Comment: Hey, figured it out! I was actually hiding the background view somewhere in my code. Set it to unhidden and now it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your image scrolls because it has been added in the tableview content and when you scroll the tableview, all the content scrolls.

But you can add the image in the superview of your tableView, behind it.
For example, if the tableView is in self.view you can try :

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newpink120"]];
imageView.frame=CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width-60, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-60-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, 60, 60);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];
```

(Make sure that the tableView has a clear backgroundColor.)